# New Yoga X1 Gen 5 random freeze, Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, lenovo, crash, yoga-2

I have a new Lenovo X1 Yoga, Gen5. It is a present for my wife, so I configured it a few weeks ago, then started using it on December 24th.  Since then it has locked up three times.  It doesn't seem to be a user interface lockup since when it happens, it disappears from my network.  I can no longer see it accessing my wifi router.  Also, if it was playing music (only one out of the three or four lockups), it stops playing.

**Machine Details:**
Hardware: ThinkPad X1 Yoga Gen 5, 16 Gig Ram, Manufactured 2020-11-26,  BIOS changed to allow virtualization for VirtualBox

OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, full disk encryption enabled, Kernel 5.4.0-58.

**Freeze Details:**
Latest lockup occurred, December 28 at 8:07 (so if anyone want to see the kern.log, that's where you can see a lockup).  The computer was in hibernation from the night before.  I opened the lid, turned the computer to get the screen orientation correct, then started typing in my password.  Got the the second letter, and the computer froze.  Verified that there was no network activity, and there wasn't so I assumed it was another hard freeze.  I used the power switch to reset and reboot.

Previous freezes occurred while streaming some music from Pandora and out via bluetooth to a speaker. Sound stopped, computer was frozen.  I think I was just moving files around and installing software.   Another freeze happened while trying to configure VirtualBox.

**What I Have Done:**
I have downloaded the **Lenovo hardware test suite**, created a bootable thumb drive, booted it and ran all of the tests.  All tests passed.

I made a **memetest86** bootable thumb drive and ran that twice.  It hammered on the memory for about 2 hours in total.  No problems reported.

I downloaded and used **Unigine Benchmark** tools to stress the GPU, again, that seemed to work.  I ran it for about 10 minutes.

I have streamed YouTube and Pandora while playing a bunch of files using VLC for 12 hours with no issues.

**How Can You Help - Please:-) :**

I have attached part of my kern.log file which will have the latest crash at time Dec 28 08:07:50 so it can be examined by someone who knows what they are looking at.  Ultimately I want to determine if this is a software issue, or do I have to send this computer back.  I also saved the entire /var/log directory in case some other information is needed.  I have until the 15th of January to return this computer so I have some time to trouble shoot this issue before I "own it."

**Additional info:**

```
~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       2.6Gi       5.6Gi       1.2Gi       7.3Gi        11Gi
Swap:         975Mi          0B       975Mi
```

```
sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60
```

```
sudo lshw -C memory
  *-memory                  
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 2
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 16GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: Row of chips LPDDR3 Synchronous 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
          vendor: Samsung
          physical id: 0
          serial: 00000000
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: [empty]
          physical id: 1
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
     *-bank:2
          description: Row of chips LPDDR3 Synchronous 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
          vendor: Samsung
          physical id: 2
          serial: 00000000
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
     *-bank:3
          description: [empty]
          physical id: 3
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: e
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 256KiB
       capacity: 256KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: f
       slot: L2 Cache
       size: 1MiB
       capacity: 1MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 10
       slot: L3 Cache
       size: 6MiB
       capacity: 6MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-firmware
       description: BIOS
       vendor: LENOVO
       physical id: 13
       version: N2WET24W (1.14 )
       date: 10/15/2020
       size: 128KiB
       capacity: 32MiB
       capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppy720 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-memory UNCLAIMED
       description: RAM memory
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
       capabilities: pm cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:ea242000-ea243fff memory:ea246000-ea246fff
```

```
 grep -i swap /etc/fstab
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

```
total 157356
drwxrwsrwt  2 root   whoopsie     4096 Dec 25 22:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root   root         4096 Jul 31 12:35 ..
-rw-r-----  1 liesel whoopsie 16509495 Dec 25 22:00 _usr_bin_nautilus.1001.crash
-rw-r-----  1 liesel whoopsie 14128454 Dec 25 11:01 _usr_bin_rhythmbox.1001.crash
-rw-r-----  1 liesel whoopsie 64553409 Dec 25 20:32 _usr_libexec_tracker-extract.1001.crash
-rw-r-----  1 liesel whoopsie 65744274 Dec 25 21:49 _usr_libexec_tracker-miner-fs.1001.crash
-rw-r-----  1 liesel whoopsie   178194 Dec 25 09:30 _usr_share_pithos_run_pithos.1001.crash
```

```
udo dmidecode -s bios-version
N2WET24W (1.14 )
```

A few lines from kern.log.  Shown is Dec 27 evening, laptop shut, then Dec 28, opened the laptop and the freeze.

```
Dec 27 20:47:33 Yogie kernel: [  843.100247] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: firmware boot complete
Dec 27 20:51:27 Yogie kernel: [ 1077.323118] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: error: no reply expected, received 0x0
Dec 27 20:51:27 Yogie kernel: [ 1077.444954] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: firmware boot complete
Dec 27 20:52:36 Yogie kernel: [ 1145.918881] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: error: no reply expected, received 0x0
Dec 27 20:52:36 Yogie kernel: [ 1146.020409] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: firmware boot complete
Dec 27 20:52:43 Yogie kernel: [ 1153.413547] wlp0s20f3: deauthenticating from 60:33:4b:e3:8d:78 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Dec 27 20:52:43 Yogie kernel: [ 1153.449678] Virtual device wlp0s20f3 asks to queue packet!
Dec 27 20:52:46 Yogie kernel: [ 1156.806104] PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
Dec 28 08:07:38 Yogie kernel: [ 1156.810941] Filesystems sync: 0.004 seconds
Dec 28 08:07:38 Yogie kernel: [ 1156.811601] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.305 seconds) done.
Dec 28 08:07:38 Yogie kernel: [ 1157.117526] OOM killer disabled.
Dec 28 08:07:38 Yogie kernel: [ 1157.117528] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
Dec 28 08:07:38 Yogie kernel: [ 1157.119568] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Dec 28 08:07:38 Yogie kernel: [ 1157.147457] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: error: no reply expected, received 0x0
Dec 28 08:07:38 Yogie kernel: [ 1157.285681] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: firmware boot complete
Dec 28 08:07:38 Yogie kernel: [ 1157.364185] e1000e: EEE TX LPI TIMER: 00000011
Dec 28 08:07:38 Yogie kernel: [ 1158.821040] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
Dec 28 08:07:38 Yogie kernel: [41645.656289] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
Dec 28 08:07:38 Yogie kernel: [41647.404007] usb 1-6: reset full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Dec 28 08:07:38 Yogie kernel: [41647.748293] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: error: no reply expected, received 0x0
Dec 28 08:07:38 Yogie kernel: [41647.852175] sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: firmware boot complete
Dec 28 08:07:38 Yogie kernel: [41648.038116] OOM killer enabled.
Dec 28 08:07:38 Yogie kernel: [41648.038117] Restarting tasks ... done.
Dec 28 08:07:38 Yogie kernel: [41648.048218] thermal thermal_zone5: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
Dec 28 08:07:38 Yogie kernel: [41648.083273] PM: suspend exit
Dec 28 08:07:38 Yogie kernel: [41648.195594] e1000e: enp0s31f6 NIC Link is Down
Dec 28 08:07:38 Yogie kernel: [41648.200358] audit: type=1400 audit(1609160858.592:63): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" pid=7852 comm="cups-browsed" capability=23  capname="sys_nice"
Dec 28 08:07:38 Yogie kernel: [41648.400692] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
Dec 28 08:07:38 Yogie kernel: [41648.546754] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
Dec 28 08:07:42 Yogie kernel: [41651.806579] wlp0s20f3: authenticate with 60:33:4b:e3:8d:78
Dec 28 08:07:42 Yogie kernel: [41651.809295] wlp0s20f3: send auth to 60:33:4b:e3:8d:78 (try 1/3)
Dec 28 08:07:42 Yogie kernel: [41651.832323] wlp0s20f3: authenticated
Dec 28 08:07:42 Yogie kernel: [41651.835463] wlp0s20f3: associate with 60:33:4b:e3:8d:78 (try 1/3)
Dec 28 08:07:42 Yogie kernel: [41651.838460] wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from 60:33:4b:e3:8d:78 (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=2)
Dec 28 08:07:42 Yogie kernel: [41651.842515] wlp0s20f3: associated
Dec 28 08:07:42 Yogie kernel: [41651.850828] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp0s20f3: link becomes ready
Dec 28 08:07:42 Yogie kernel: [41651.919250] wlp0s20f3: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by 60:33:4b:e3:8d:78
Dec 28 08:07:49 Yogie kernel: [41659.374833] audit: type=1400 audit(1609160869.764:64): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/gdm/greeter/applications/gnome-initial-setup.desktop" pid=2277 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1001 ouid=0
Dec 28 08:07:49 Yogie kernel: [41659.397344] audit: type=1400 audit(1609160869.788:65): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/gdm/greeter/applications/gnome-initial-setup.desktop" pid=2277 comm="pool-org.gnome." requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1001 ouid=0
Dec 28 08:07:50 Yogie kernel: [41659.799485] audit: type=1326 audit(1609160870.192:66): auid=1001 uid=1001 gid=1001 ses=3 pid=2277 comm="pool-org.gnome." exe="/snap/snap-store/518/usr/bin/snap-store" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=93 compat=0 ip=0x7f65b80154e7 code=0x50000
\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00Dec 28 08:41:51 Yogie kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 5.4.0-58-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-004) (gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)) #64-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 9 08:16:25 UTC 2020 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-58.64-generic 5.4.73)
Dec 28 08:41:51 Yogie kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.4.0-58-generic root=/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
Dec 28 08:41:51 Yogie kernel: [    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
Dec 28 08:41:51 Yogie kernel: [    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
Dec 28 08:41:51 Yogie kernel: [    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
Dec 28 08:41:51 Yogie kernel: [    0.000000]   Hygon HygonGenuine
Dec 28 08:41:51 Yogie kernel: [    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
Dec 28 08:41:51 Yogie kernel: [    0.000000]   zhaoxin   Shanghai  
Dec 28 08:41:51 Yogie kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'
Dec 28 08:41:51 Yogie kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE registers'
,,,
```

Comment: I have the same model, Xubuntu 20.04 installed, and also experience intermittent freezes. If this happens, the machine is completely unresponsive, I cannot Ctrl+Alt+F1 to the console, and cannot ssh into the machine. So far, it has happened twice in the course of a few days. I do not use hibernation and both times it just occurred completely randomly, while the machine wasn't doing anything special. Nothing in kern.log to indicate what this might be related to, but with such a hard freeze, I would not expect anything to show up in the log anyway.

Comment: Because mine passed so many hardware tests I'm going to keep it, and hope that the issue resolves with updates.  Not sure how many of us Linux user have the machine, but as more people buy them, maybe we will get an answer.  Are you keeping yours?

Comment: Yes, I am also hoping this will eventually resolve itself (maybe with the 5.8 kernel, coming with 20.04.2). I read quite a bit about freezes with Firefox (last freeze yesterday happened while starting to watch a youtube video), so I am switching to a different browser for now to see if this helps. Might also be related to the sound / pulseaudio / rtkit-daemon (the sound usually goes into a ~1 sec loop when I get a freeze) and you also mentioned streaming/listening to music during a freeze. Do you also get looping sound? Do these freezes occur especially when audio is used?

Comment: I recently upgraded to the 5.8 kernel. I haven't had any freezes since. I am hopeful that this has fixed the issue.

Comment: I didn't get the sound looping when mine crashed and I was listening to music one of the times it locked up. Other times I wasn't listening to anything.  I was considering upgrading to 20.10, so I made a boot USB to try it out, but the touchscreen would not auto rotate.  I am however encouraged by your report.