# System totally freezes and audio loops

Tags: sound, freeze, intel, microcode

My laptop with Ubuntu 20.04 totally freezes at random times and audio loops what was playing the last 1 or 2 seconds before freezing. I can't switch to another tty and Alt + SysRq + REISUB does absolutely nothing. System logs don't show anything strange, but I have found other users with a similar problem on other distros and the freezes should be related to Intel CPUs (My laptop has an Intel i3-5010u).
I don't think this is related but I've been using dwm, and I don't think this has happened to me while i was using Gnome.
The only thing that seems wrong is that this error:
[ 3515.974328] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Microcode SW error detected.  Restarting 0x2000000.
keeps repeating forever.

**EDIT:
Disabling iommu seems to resolve this, no freezes since yesterday. I'll update this post in a few days if no freezes occur.**

Comment: Not sure any one here can help you as a quick search of the error shows it to be a know bug with that CPU not a Ubuntu problem per sec.

Comment: No idea if this is related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1304021/new-yoga-x1-gen-5-random-freeze-ubuntu-20-04 But when I get these freezes, then I also get that 1-2 sec audio loop. CPU is rather different though on this laptop (i7-10510U).